# Printing Contents of TableView in Swift IOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making an app with a scene that contains a tableview. Each cell in the table view contains a rating control (made up of 5 stars) and a label. At the click of a button I would like to print all of the labels as well as the number of stars that user has clicked from the rating controls from the entire table view. to the console.

How can I do this?

Here is my tableview(_:cellForRowAt:) method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier
    let cellId = "cell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? MatchingTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instacne of MatchingTableViewCell")
    }

    // Fetches the appropriate match for the data source layout.
    let match = matching[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = match.name
    cell.photoImagView.image = match.photo
    cell.ratingControl.rating = match.rating

    return cell
}
```

Data model object is an array of structs of Match objects:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import os.log

class Match: NSObject, NSCoding {
// MARK: Properties
var name: String
var photo: UIImage?
var rating: Int


// MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("matching")

// MARK: Types
struct PropertyKey {
    static let name = "name"
    static let photo = "photo"
    static let rating = "rating"
}

init?(name: String, photo: UIImage?, rating: Int) {
    // The name must not be empty
    guard !name.isEmpty else{
        return nil
    }
    // The rating must be between 0 and 5 inclusively
    guard (rating >= 0) && (rating <= 5) else {
        return nil
    }
    // Initialize stored properties
    self.name = name
    self.photo = photo
    self.rating = rating
}

override var description : String {
    return "rating \(self.rating) \n"
}
// MARK: NSCoding
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
    aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
    aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.rating)

}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // The name is required if we cannot decode a name string, the init should fail
    guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else{
        os_log("Unable to decode the name for a Match object", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        return nil
    }
    // Because the photo is an optional property of Match, just use conditional cast.
    let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage
    let rating = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.rating)

    // Must call designated init
    self.init(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating as! Int)

}
```

}

RatingControl.swiift:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RatingControl: UIStackView {



// MARK: Properties
private var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
var rating = 0 {
    didSet {
        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var starSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 44.0, height: 44.0) {// Defines size of buttons/
    didSet{
        setupButtons()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var starCount: Int = 5 {// Defines number of buttons
    didSet{
        setupButtons()
    }
}

// MARK: Initialization
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupButtons()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupButtons()
}

      // MARK: Private Methods
private func setupButtons(){


    // Clear any existing buttons
    for button in ratingButtons{
        removeArrangedSubview(button)
        button.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    ratingButtons.removeAll()

    // Load Button Images
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let filledStar = UIImage(named: "filledStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)
    let emptyStar = UIImage(named: "emptyStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)
    let highligtedStar = UIImage(named: "highlightedStar", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)

    for _ in 0..<starCount {
    // Create the button
    let button = UIButton()

    // Set the button images
        button.setImage(emptyStar, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(filledStar, for: .selected)
        button.setImage(highligtedStar, for: .highlighted)
        button.setImage(highligtedStar, for: [.highlighted, .selected])

    // Adding constraints
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // disables buttons automatically generated constraints
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.height).isActive = true // defines height
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: starSize.width).isActive = true // defines width

    //Setup the button action
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    // Add button to stack
    addArrangedSubview(button)

    // Add the new button to the rating button Array
    ratingButtons.append(button)
    }
    updateButtonSelectionStates()
}

// MARK: Button Action
@objc func ratingButtonTapped(button:UIButton){

    guard let index = ratingButtons.index(of: button) else {
        fatalError("The button, \(button), is not in the ratingButtons array: \(ratingButtons)")
    }
    // Calculate the rating of the selected button
    let selectedRating = index + 1
    if selectedRating == rating { // If the selected star represents the current rating, reset the rating to 0
        rating = 0
    } else{
        // Otherwise set the rating to the selected star
        rating = selectedRating
    }
}
private func updateButtonSelectionStates() { // Update buttons appearance
    for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
        // If the index of a button is less than the rating, that button should be selected
        button.isSelected = index < rating
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You've got this wrong. Your table view does not save data, it displays it. You want to have a data model that holds the values you display from your table view. That's what feeds your tableView dataSource methods. Often it will be an array of structs.

You want to print the contents of your table view's data model.

### Edit:

Now that you've provided that info we can help you.

Add `CustomStringConvertible` conformance to your data model:

```
class Match: NSObject, NSCoding, CustomStringConvertible  {
```

The only requirement for `CustomStringConvertible` is that you provide a computed property `description` that's a `String`:

```
var description: String {
   return "Match(name:\(name),rating:\(rating))"
}
```

Then in your button action

```
@IBAction func logInfo(sender: UIButton) {
    matching.forEach { print($0) }
}
```

Since your `Match` class now conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, you can print `Match` objects directly.

Or if you want indexes:

```
@IBAction func logInfo(sender: UIButton) {
    matching.enumerated()forEach { print(String(format:"%02l", $0.0) + ": " + $0.1) }
}
```

Comment: I am asking how to do that. You're just restating what I asked.

Comment: In order to help you with that you will need to edit your question and add your data model object, and perhaps your `tableview(_:cellForRowAt:)` method.

Comment: I have updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: Okay, this prints them out but it always says the rating is 5 even if a different amount of stars is selected.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your code that updates the data model when the user changes the rating. Add that code to your question.

Comment: I don't think I have code to update the data model. I am not sure how to do that

Comment: So post your code that handles the user changing the number of stars.

Comment: updated with requested code that handles the user changing the number of stars

Comment: It looks like you have a custom object, `RatingControl`, that handles displaying the user's rating, and responding to taps to show a new rating. however, it doesn't do anything with that information. You need to define a protocol that the `RatingControl` would use to communicate changes in the rating selection, give the `RatingControl` a delegate that conforms to that protocol, and set up the owning view controller as the delegate of each `RatingControl`. Then when the user changes a rating you need to save that information into your data model at the correct array index.